# How can i select the complete row for different components in UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, ios6, uipickerview

I have 4 components in PickerView. I want to select the complete row in all the components when row 0 of component 0 is selected. Similarly, for every other row of each components. Is there any way to extend the single selection for all?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that if the user selects row 1 of component 0, you want to automatically select row 1 of components 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't want selection to be confined to only one row of a component. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `UIPickerView` delegate method `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:`.

```
// called when a user selects a row
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // This code assumes all four components have the same number of rows
    for (NSInteger c = 0; c < pickerView.numberOfComponent; c++) {
        if (c != component) {
            [pickerView selectRow:row inComponent:c animated:NO]; // animate if desired
        }
    }

    // do any other desired actions (if any) when a row is selected
}
```

Another option would be to have just one component showing all four sets of data in each row. Having 4 components doesn't make a lot of sense if the user can't ever select different values for each component.

Comment: Any solution to this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13339856/is-there-any-way-to-find-uipickerview-component-data-using-uisearchbar